# How to add two scanner strings together? in 'if' statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to add two strings of data together from a scanner object.

I'm wanting to say

```
if(age.equals("child")) AND sex.equals("male")) THEN System.out.println etc;
```

This code below is all I have so far. I also have a code:    sex.equals("male")

```
if(age.equals("child")){
        System.out.println("1. Male child shirts are on the 5th floor");
        System.out.println("2. Male child trousers are on the 6th floor");
        System.out.println("3. Male child shoes are on the 6th floor");
    }
```

I hope this isn't too confusing. I'm new to learning Java and only just learning the terminology.

Thanks

Comment: Use `&&` for "AND" - http://www.dummies.com/programming/java/logical-operators-in-java/

Comment: `if (age.equals("child) && sex.equals("male"))` -- this is called "and"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(age.equals("something") && sex.equals("your_var")){
        System.out.println("your response")
    }
```